# How to fetch the data from a php through ajax in the jquery fullcalendar when click prev r next function

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, xml, fullcalendar

I want  to  get the function for the specific event:

```
$('#my-prev-button').click(function() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('prev');
});
```

and i have a code for the full calendar event i want to do it specifically for the prev or next event and i want to get the start and end date from that function please help me friends and currently by the coding i given bellow its returning the current date

Jquery part:

```
 $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                //                 theme:true,
                    header: {
                        left: 'prev,next today',
                        center: 'title',
                        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                    },
                    defaultDate:"2014-11-01",
        events: function(start, end, timezone, callback) {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'myxmlfeed.php',
                type:'post',
                dataType: 'html',
                data: {

                    start: start.format(),
                    end: end.format()
                },
                success: function(doc) {
                    var events = [];
                    $(doc).find('event').each(function() {
                        events.push({
                            title: $(this).attr('title'),
                            start: $(this).attr('start'), // will be parsed
                            end: $(this).attr('end')
                        });
                    });


          callback(events);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

XML part:

```
<xml>
<event id="1" title="first entry" url="http://www.google.com" start="2014-12-22" />
<?php 
$start = $_GET['start'];
?>

<event id="2" title="first entry" url="http://www.google.com" start="<?php $start; ?>" />
<event id="3" title="fir entry" url="http://www.google.com" end="<?php $_GET['end']; ?>" /> 
</xml>
```

Comment: Tried using http://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/viewRender/ instead? Or does it have to be the 'prev' and 'next' buttons? If so, it's probably easiest to just add a listener to the buttons after you've rendered the calendar

Comment: r u having any sample codes pls provide that becoz already one of the friend told too use view display which has a same functionality but its nt working for me

Comment: [viewRender](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/viewRender/) `viewRender: function(view, element) { do stuff },`

Comment: i have used viewRender and displayed the view.intervalStart and view.intervalEnd but i dono how to display it in a normal date  format i used Date() also but its nt displaying the current month date

Answer (score 1):

you can use viewDisplay callback

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({         
    viewDisplay: function(view) {
         callBackfn(view.visStart ,view.visEnd);
   }
});
```

you can get start and end date like this

```
function callBackfn(startDate,endDate){ 
   var datesArray = getDates(startDate,endDate);

}
```

Comment: i think view display is removed in fullcalendar.. jquery http://fullcalendar.io/docs1/removed/viewDisplay/

Comment: it's deprecated,not removed from system. have you tried above code,working?

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({         
    viewDisplay: function(view) {
         callBackfn(view.visStart ,view.visEnd);
   }
});
 function callBackfn(startDate,endDate){ 
   var datesArray = getDates(startDate,endDate);
   alert(datesArray);

}
      });

Comment: is it necessary to call the "function callBackfn" any where in the coding because i can't get ur answer properly please help me

Comment: yes you have to call function callBackfn on same page.Try the same code provided

Comment: have you changed viewDisplay to viewRender?